# How to remove node mirror pod creation only?

Tags: kubernetes

Did someone already get this error : pods "k8s-debian9-charming-but-youthful-merkle" is forbidden: pod does not have "kubernetes.io/config.mirror" annotation, node "k8s-uk1-node-002" can only create mirror pods ?

Why the node is configured to create only mirror pods ? How to unconfigure this ? Is this RBAC policies ?

I created the kubernetes cluster with terraform and ansible on an openstack, with kubespray

Any help is welcome,
thanks by advance,
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NodeRestriction admission plugin is responsible for enforcing that limitation, to prevent nodes from creating pods that expand their access to resources like serviceaccounts and secrets unrelated to their existing workloads

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this error and realized (after a couple of hours) that the environment variable, `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST` was set incorrectly.

Comment: What did you set it to?